# App engine php setup

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, installation, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my web app on google cloud platform, after success deploy on gcp, i have a problem when i want to login into my web app, the login is successfull, but the homepage showing a **blank page**. there's no error showing on error_reporting.

i've checked the **session**, app engine doesn't get the **user_data** when i success after login. is there something wrong when i make a **http_request**?

```
public function http_request($url, $data=array())
      {
          $curl = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
          curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
            ));
          $resp = curl_exec($curl);

          if (!$resp) {
              return curl_error($curl);
          } else {
              return $resp;
          }
          curl_close($curl);
      }
```

i use CodeIgniter and using phpCurl to fetch the httprequest,anybody help me please? i already spent 3 days for solving this and got nothing.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please show config.php, and your controller

Comment: Can you get the error message from the stackdriver logging request logs? Docs on how to do this are at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#using_the_logs_viewer